# Is it possible to make only box colliders in unity2d tilemaps colliders 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made tiles with some sprites but not all of them is square. So this happend:[image]

I'm using:

[image]

Is it possible to make colliders square?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I just need to change tiles Collider Type to Grid